# How to redirect to home page if URL is invalid?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redirect, react-router-v4

I am using React and React-router v4

Here is my route component:

```
<Switch>
              {/* <Route path='/blog' exact component={Blog} /> */}
              <Route path='/projects/:id' component={ProjectDetails} />
              <Route path='/career/:id' component={CareerDetails} />
              <Route path='/' component={withScrollPreservation(LandingPage)} />
              <Route component={withScrollPreservation(LandingPage)} />
            </Switch>
```

What is my question:

If user types something that is not valid from routes give I want it to redirect to home page. Consider this scenario running this locally:

`localhost:4000/` - home page

`localhiost:4000/invalidurl` - should redirect back to `localhost:4000/` and deleteting invalidurl from url

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can make use of [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) component

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri - I am having an issue when user entered manually on the browser like localhost:9090/{invalidurl}/{invalidUrl} . I have raised the question as well , link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261462/react-router-dom-redirect-is-not-working-for-nested-routes-eg-localhost90 . Please give some idea , how to do it,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and add this route inside your switch:

```
<Route render={() => <Redirect to={{pathname: "/"}} />} />
```

It'll catch anything that has no route.

Comment: For me this did redirect but wouldn't display the component in the ```exact path="/"```

Comment: Make sure this route is the last element of your switch

Comment: There's a slight problem with this answer, when the user reloads the page they're redirected to the above path. So this `<Route path='/blog' exact component={Blog} />` when reloaded will take you to `path="/"`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to redirect home page when type invalid path string so that follow this code....

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
   <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
   <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
   <Route path="/user" component={User} onEnter={this.requireAuth}/>
   <Route path="*" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

here i used * in path that means if invalid path string type then it auto redirect to home page.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I've used previous solution and it worked like a charm, But thank you a lot as well!