# React router dom : <Redirect/> is not working for invalid nested path's like localhost:9090/{invalidaa}/{invalidb}/{invalidc}

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement the Notmatch or Invalid routes when the user typed on URI (in browser). Below is my router component .
Below `<Redirect/>` is working when the URI `localhost:9090/{something}` it redirect to `\` page , but when the **URI is invalid** like `localhost:9090/{invalidyyy}/{invalidxx}` not showed anything on the screen . Please help / suggest me to overcome the same .

Update : I render the below component inside App component like

```
App.js 

render(){
return( <RenderRoutes/> )
}
```

```
const renderRoutes = () => {
    
    console.log('isAuthrenderRoute',isAuth);
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/"
                        render={props => (
                            <AppRoute Component={Login} props={props} />
                        )}
                    />    
                        <Route
                            exact={true} path="/xxx/ForgotPassword"
                            render={props => (
                        <LandingPage>
                                <AppRoute  Component={ForgotPassword} props={props} />
                        </LandingPage> 
                            )}
                        />
                    <Redirect exact to="/" />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
};

const AppRoute = ({ Component, Layout, props }) => {
    if (Layout) {
        return (
            <Layout {...props}>
                <Component {...props} />
            </Layout>
        );
    }

    if (!Component) {
        return <Layout {...props} />;
    }

    return <Component {...props} />;
};

export default renderRoutes;
```

Comment: Is the React app loading at all? What do you see in the console and network tab?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but I think you should make the `Route` components direct children of the `Switch` component. E.g. `LandingPage` should be inside the Route's render function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I updated my question . is tht answers your question

Comment: @Christiaan i am not able to catch your point please let me give some code samples .,

Answer (score 0):

The `Switch` component renders the first component that will match the routes conditions. In order for this to work properly, you should only use `<Route />` components as children. The reason why the `<Redirect />` does work, is because when none of the routes matches, it will fallback to the redirect component because it is not a Route.

You are now rendering the `<LandingPage>` component as child of the `<Switch>` component. Which results in that component always being rendered by the Switch. However, the page will be empty because the Route component doesn't match the current location.

Here is your code which should work:

```
const renderRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={props => (
              <AppRoute Component={Login} props={props} />
            )}
          />
          {(isAuth !== null || isAuth !== false) && (
            <Route
              exact={true} path="/xxx/ForgotPassword"
              render={props => (
                <LandingPage>
                  <AppRoute Component={ForgotPassword} props={props} />
                </LandingPage>
              )}
            />
          )}
          <Redirect exact to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: You are using the `<LandingPage>` in your code example, make sure you keep the imports intact in the original file.

Comment: yes landing page is working now . But still this type of invalid routes **localhost:9009/aa/bb** is not redirect to ``` \ ```` . it only redirect when the uri is localhost:9090/{invalidstring} .@Christiaan

Comment: Ok, could you provide a working example using https://codesandbox.io or something simular?

Comment: I found the answer , i supposed to add ``` <base href="\" />``` in index html  file . Now its working, really thanks for your response ..